# Does vue contain blocks funcionality like in djagno

Tags: django, vue.js

I'm working on new web project. Previously I was keeping everything in one project (django). This time I decided to split it on two separate projects - backend (django) and frontend vue. I haven't worked with raw vue project so here is my question - Can I use blocks in vue ? My goal is to create one main template with nav bar, footer and the middle div for other views, just like in django blocks. I could import these components in each view but it is not elegant and I bet there must be some other solution.

Comment: I'd give you rather a hint than a complete answer. Use Vue-components https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html. Components - is about reusable parts of your web-UI, not equivalent or even similar to django templating, but you also can split your system into managable pieces of code with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your implementation you could use nested routes and something similar to this if routing is handled on the front-end:

```
<html>

  ...

  <body>
     // code outside here

     // vue component taken from route
     <router-view></router-view>

    // more code outside here
  </body>

  ... 

</html>
```

You can find more information about Vue router [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/)

Alternatively, you could have a base component with slots for other parts of your project:

```
<template>
    <div>
    
       <header-component></header-component>
    
       <div>
    
         <nav-component>
           <slot name="..."></slot>
         </nav-component>
    
         <main>
           <slot name="..."></slot>
         </main>
    
       </div>
    
    </div>
</template>
```